# How to turn a subroutine into a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction

I've written a subroutine that takes in 6 matrices and after some manipulation returns back 3 new ones.

I will use this subroutine fairly often in this notebook so I think it would be easier to turn the whole process into a function `M[matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4, matrix5, matrix6]`. Is there a way to do this?

```
Clear[data1P, data1N, data2P, data2N, data3P, data3N, i]
data1P = matrixIN1;
data2P = matrixIN2; 
data3P = matrixIN3; 
data1N = matrixIN4; 
data2N = matrixIN5;
data3N = matrixIN6;

For[i = 1, i <= Length[data2P], i++,
 AppendTo[data1P, data2P[[i]]];
 AppendTo[data1N, data2N[[i]]];
]

For[i = 1, i <= Length[data3P], i++,
 AppendTo[data1P, data3P[[i]]];
 AppendTo[data1N, data3N[[i]]];
]

matrixOUT1 = data1P;
matrixOUT2= data1N;

matrixOUTp3 = 
  matrixOUT1[[All, 2]] - 
   matrixOUT2[[All, 2]];

matrixOUT3 = 
  Table[{matrixOUT1[[i,1]], matrixOUTp3[[i]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[matrixOUTp3]}];
```

Comment: ...and where is this "subroutine" you speak of? Hard to recommend anything without seeing it.

Comment: @J.M. Let me recommend a `Module` though :)

Comment: @Kuba, it depends; you sometimes can get away without a scoping construct, at the cost of deep nesting. ;)

Comment: Instead of using `AppendTo[]`, have you looked into using `Join[]`?

Comment: I will now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code converted to function + some corrections:

```
function[arrays : {__?ArrayQ}] := Module[{
   temp1, temp2, temp3
   },
  temp1 = Join @@ arrays[[{1, 2}]];
  temp2 = Join @@ arrays[[{4, 5}]];

  temp3 = Transpose[{
     temp1[[;; , 1]],
     temp1[[;; , 2]] - temp2[[;; 2]]
     }];

  {temp1, temp2, temp3}

 ]
```

There is no check if appropriate matrices are of the same length but your code doesn't contain any either.

Things you should read about:

[Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html), [Functions as Procedures tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAsProcedures.html), [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), [Join](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html), [PatternTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)