# Turning computation in a notebook into a function

Tags: functions, notebooks

I have a piece of code that I'd like to turn into a function.
I'm aware of modules and saw [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112144/how-to-turn-a-subroutine-into-a-function). The problem is that my code is quite long, containing all kinds of functions of the form `fun[x_]:=...`, numerical integrations, eigensystems and so on, and it seems `Module` doesn't handle that very well (or perhaps I'm just not using it correctly).

I've also looked [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Importing_and_running_nb_file_inside_another_in_mathematica2), where it is described how to call a notebook from another notebook. This should work, but I was wondering if there is a way to really treat the notebook as a function with inputs I can pass to, similarly to most all other programming languages.

Comment: You might see if you could use a technique like this `f[x_]:=Module[{}, a[y_]:=Sin[y]; b[z_]:=z^2; b[a[x]] ]; f[2]` which wraps `Module` around all the functions in your notebook and then calls the `Module`.

Comment: Smth similar is discussed here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1752195, especially see the last post in that thread by Alan Calvitti, but see disadvantages also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could quite literally do the following, but it is not nice because of all sorts of scoping problems,

```
myNotebookFunction[var1_, var2_] := Module[{},    (* add this as the first line of your notebook *)
                                                  (* adjust number of vars *)

(* notebook as is goes here *)

result ]  (* add this as last line to close Module. Result is what you want returned *)
```

`myNotebookFunction[ var1, var2 ]` will then be available after doing `Get["notebookfile.nb"]`.

However, its horrible. What you should be doing is turning your notebook into a simple package. To find out how to do that, type the following into a Text cell in any notebook, highlight it with the mouse, then press F1 to get the documentation:

tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages

Comment: You don't even need `Module` as a wrapper. Just putting all code between parentheses `(....)` is enough. Be sure though to separate all individual blocks of code with semicolons `;`, otherwise you'll accidentally multiply things together.